# Progressive Web App doesn't fetch my cached files

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch, progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

I am trying to turn my weather app into a PWA, and I want to create an offline page if the user lose the connection.
So I've managed to put the html and related ressources (like scripts or svg) into the browser's cache, but when I got offline, only the html page load, and not the other stuff...

Here is the files that are in the cache :[image: Files in the cache]

And here is the errors that occur in the console and in the network when I got offline :[image: Console errors][image: Network errors]

As you see, only the KUTE.js library (that doesn't work even if apparently loaded ???) that comes from a CDN and the things imported by the CSS (I put the CSS directly in my html page) are loaded.

--- If you wonder what's the "en" file, it's because I made a translation system with Express, Ejs and cookies, and so when you go to /en or /fr in the url, it will translate the page either in english or french. ---

Finally, here is the code of my service worker :

```
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";
const OFFLINE_URL = "offline.html";
const BASE = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
const CACHED_FILES = [
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/kute.js@2.1.2/dist/kute.min.js",
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/favicon.ico`,
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png`,
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png`,
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png`,
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/favicon-16x16.png`,
  `${BASE}/src/favicon/favicon-32x32.png`,
  `${BASE}/src/svg/layered-waves.svg`,
  `${BASE}/js/background.js`,
  `${BASE}/js/animation-blob.js`
];

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async() => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    await Promise.all(
      [...CACHED_FILES, OFFLINE_URL].map((path) => {
        return cache.add(new Request(path, {cache: "reload"}));
      })
    );
  })());

  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
      await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
    }
  })());

  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if(event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith((async() => {
      try {
        const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
        if(preloadResponse) {
          return preloadResponse;
        }

        return await fetch(event.request);
      } catch(e) {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        return await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

It's the "*regular*" code for creating an offline page, except that I add multiple files to the cache.

So do you know why I can't fetch my other cached files ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

this function act as a proxy to know if it should fetch data from cache or net wetwork :

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if(event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith((async() => {
      try {
        const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
        if(preloadResponse) {
          return preloadResponse;
        }

        return await fetch(event.request);
      } catch(e) {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        return await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

but this line `if(event.request.mode === "navigate")` make a special behavior only if it's a navigate request (when navigator load a new page). So you need  some minor change to make it work, you can try something like this :

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith((async() => {
    try {
      const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
      if(preloadResponse) {
        return preloadResponse;
      }

      return await fetch(event.request);
    } catch(e) {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      return await cache.match(event.request);
    }
  })());
});
```

This will normaly make it work but now every resquest will now pass through ServiceWorker and not only `navigate` one

Comment: Thank you ! But this mean that if for example the CDN that I fetch is not available, it will load the offline page ?

Comment: Yes it will work ! if you have store url in cache it's good ;) ( i make a little change to my code, don't forget to upgrade ! )